# Website resolution problems in different computers using asp.net 2.0 version

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I developed one website in asp.net 2.0 version, but I am getting the problem of resolution, the problem is in my personal computer website showing good and full website, but in my laptop website is not showing full website, only half side. But both system resolution is different. Below example of screen shot of my website.
http://postimg.org/image/blagh6zzz/
And my css code is:

```
.slider{padding:0px 0px 0px 80px}.rep{padding:0px 58px;}.rep2{padding:0px 58px;}.logo{  background:url(../image/Logo.png) no-repeat 0 0; }.header{ padding:0px 0px 0px 250px;}
.lnk{ padding:0px 0px 0px 850px;}.wrapper{  position:absolute;}.kit{ padding:10px 0px 0px 75px;}.mix{padding:10px 0px 0px 75px;}.logo{ margin-left:820px;margin-top: -50px;}
img {text-decoration: none; border: 0px}.navigation.a{text-decoration: none; border: 0px;}.social{ padding:0px 0px 20px 780px} .mrep{margin-left:80px;}.line{margin-left:80px; background:url(../image/line3.JPG);  height:2px; width:840px; }.line1{ margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:20px;  background:url(../image/line3.JPG);  height:2px; width:840px; }
.navigation{padding:40px 0px 0px 80px;}.logo{ padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;}.ndisplay{padding:0px 0px 0px 90px;margin-top:-70px;}
```

And I used body style in html side blow code:

```
body{background-image:url('image/bg.jpg');}
```

I think, I am not good at css, but how to fix this problem and also used one jquery plugin in my website that also have css code but not posting.

Comment: May be your laptop is wide screen. :-)

Comment: if you post the *direct* link to the image, someone will be able to update your question to include it. I, like others, am unwilling to click on random links from questions

Comment: Ya. My laptop has wide screen, but website should show similar to all computers and laptop.

Comment: Any way can you write the css code to fix this problem.Sayse and milan m

Comment: Have you thought of using percentages in your css instead of fixed values?

Comment: No, I have not thought, but I am using padding most of my all div and see my above css code. SilentDoc

Comment: create your site for 4:3 resolutions and then wrap it in a container which will be centered... on wide screen will will be on center

Comment: Still getting same problem nothing change as previous result. I applied to the body{width:100%} and wrapper{margin:0 auto}

Answer (score 0):

put on your first container (the one right below body) a css like

```
[selector] 
{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: .wrapper{position:absolute;}, I used wrapper class, not a container and I have put your css code in the body or wrapper. Still confused

Comment: body{margin: 0 auto;width:100%;height:100%; background-image:url('image/bg.jpg');}, I have to write like that I think so.

Comment: body{width: 100%};   div.wrapper{margin: 0 auto;} ... anyway, put your code on jsFiddle and explain your issue

Comment: Still getting same problem nothing change as previous result. I applied to the body{width:100%} and wrapper{margin:0 auto}